# Password RegEx - Minimum 12 char, Should contain 1 Uppercase & Lowercase & Number & Special Char and should not contain more than 2 repeated char

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am looking for an password regEx. which should cover the following conditions

1. 1 Uppercase
2. 1 Lowercase
3. 1 Number
4. 1 Special Char
5. should not contain more than 2 repeated char (Eg: SaaC - allowed, Saaac - Not allowed)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

`/^(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{2})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{12,})/.test('some-text-here')`